# Deploying a Flask/Django app with AWS OpsWorks

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

Right, so I am very new to AWS OpsWorks, and when I try and install a vanilla `python` app via a custom cookbook, it gives me this error:

"No resource or method named `ensure_scm_package_installed`"

I have tried using most of the custom cookbooks available through Google, like https://github.com/alecpm/opsworks-web-python.

Could anyone help with this? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you really need OpsWorks?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov Yeah company-wide policy

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for your question as I've ran into the same issue now. I can say that you are having `deploy` named cookbook inside your recipes branch, and `metadata.rb` file inside that cookbook. So internally opsworks is going to replace default `metadata.rb` with your `metadata.rb`.

So your `metadata.rb` might not have all the cookbooks dependencies defined in this file. Hence the error. You can see official `Chef 11.10` deploy cookbook from [this link](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/deploy).

For more advanced info :

- `Current Recipes path` : /opt/aws/opsworks/current
- `Your recipes path` : /opt/aws/opsworks/current/site-cookbooks
- `Opsworks default recipes path` : /opt/aws/opsworks/current/cookbooks
- `Final recipes path` : /opt/aws/opsworks/current/merged-cookbooks

So now simply go to final recipes path and you can see that `deploy` cookbook's `metadata.rb` file is yours (not combined with default cookbook). Hence all the errors are coming. Hope this helps someone like me.